# Write to multiple file descriptors with minimal syscalls

Tags: sockets, go, file-descriptor, splice

I have a REST API that also serves SSE's to send events to clients. The expected load can be anywhere up to 10k concurrent. Luckily since the client never sends data we don't have to worry about polling the connections, however our next bottleneck becomes sending data to the FDs.

We broadcast a static payload out to either all the connections, or a subset of them. Is there a good way to do this without without spending over 60% of our profiled CPU time inside of syscall?

I've seen some talk around tcp splicing such that we `vmsplice` our payload into a pipe then `tee` it into n many pipes, then splice into n many socket. But is this the ideal way of achieving it?

Could something like `memfd_create` + `sendfile` work?

Is going to these lengths even worth it to save copying the payload ~10k times?